# failed to launch preferred application for category TerminalEmulator?

Tags: linux

I get this error:

> Failed to launch preferred application for category "TerminalEmulator".

[image: error dialog "Failed to launch preferred application for category "TerminalEmulator""]

Answer (score 14):

### Step 1

Go to applications and search for `qterminal` and open QTerminal.

This will open a terminal.

### Step 2

Type `sudo apt install xfce4-settings`, hit enter, wait for process to complete.

Now you can use all your applications.

Comment: This worked great for me trying to get the "Open Terminal Here" button to work in Thunar (even though I am not otherwise using xfce4)

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of scrapping through various answers which asked to install or update various things, all just was for NO LUCK!
Then I decided to do it in my own lazy way.
I donot have any problem with QTerminal, hence I just tweak some parts in the thunar and settings.

1. In thunar(file manager) > Edit > Configure custom actions > Open Terminal Here (If this tag is not available then create it or if there is multiple tags with same value then keep only one and delete other)>double click on it to open and customize it.
   In the next box you'll see "command" which will be run when clicking on "Open Terminal Here". Just dont write any command manually. There on the right side a "Select Application" icon is present. Just click it and select your preferred terminal. Save this change and Bingo! you'll be opening the folder in your preferred terminal.
   now you'll see the command (basically path to the terminal application with a modifier f to open folder). Select only the application path and copy it, we'll need it in step 2.
2. In this step we will set up just tweak setting
   Setting>Keyboard>Shortcuts
   if Ctrl+Alt+T is already defined here then just edit it or create new "Custom shortcut"
   paste the copied path of the terminal (what we copied in step 1) in the command section. Save it

DONE!!! *** You can set any shortcut key for your convenience ***

Comment: Great research for finding out this has to do something with Thunar.

Answer (score 0):

> There on the right side a "Select Application" icon is present. Just click it and select your preferred terminal.

```
/usr/bin/alacritty --working-directory %f
```